Does the Talmud ever call the righteous gentile as part of Israel?
Does the Talmud anywhere say that the righteous gentile is part of Israel or of God's people?

I'm not sure. But doesn't the Bible say that all the righteous are Gods people?

Why would you think they should be? Why is being a righteous gentile not enough on its own?

Are you asking if a non-Jew is part of the Jewish people?

relevant: Can a Gentile theist be saved?

I’m asking if a non Jew is part of Israel, not if we are Jews

@Mider2009 The English word “Jew” ultimately comes from the Hebrew word that meant “Judaean”, meaning, a person from the last intact Israelite kingdom before the exile. The term eventually expanded to cover the wider Israelite nation as a whole. The term “Jew” thus refers to any member of the nation of Israel. Therefore, being an Israelite is synonymous with being a Jew, and you cannot be one without being the other.

QwertyCTRL Abraham and the patriarchs were not Jewish

No, but
Yad HaChazaka Teshuva 3:5
בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁשּׁוֹקְלִין עֲוֹנוֹת אָדָם עִם זְכֻיּוֹתָיו אֵין מְחַשְּׁבִין עָלָיו עָוֹן שֶׁחָטָא בּוֹ תְּחִלָּה וְלֹא שֵׁנִי אֶלָּא מִשְּׁלִישִׁי וְאֵילָךְ. אִם נִמְצְאוּ עֲוֹנוֹתָיו מִשְּׁלִישִׁי וְאֵילָךְ מְרֻבִּין עַל זְכֻיּוֹתָיו אוֹתָם שְׁתֵּי עֲוֹנוֹת מִצְטָרְפִים וְדָנִין אוֹתוֹ עַל הַכּל. וְאִם נִמְצְאוּ זְכֻיּוֹתָיו כְּנֶגֶד עֲוֹנוֹתָיו אֲשֶׁר מֵעָוֹן שְׁלִישִׁי וְאֵילָךְ מַעֲבִירִים כָּל עֲוֹנוֹתָיו רִאשׁוֹן רִאשׁוֹן. לְפִי שֶׁהַשְּׁלִישִׁי נֶחְשָׁב רִאשׁוֹן שֶׁכְּבָר נִמְחֲלוּ הַשְּׁנַיִם. וְכֵן הָרְבִיעִי הֲרֵי הוּא רִאשׁוֹן שֶׁכְּבָר נִמְחַל הַשְּׁלִישִׁי וְכֵן עַד סוֹפָן. בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים בְּיָחִיד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (איוב לג כט) "הֶן כָּל אֵלֶּה יִפְעַל אֵל פַּעֲמַיִם שָׁלוֹשׁ עִם גָּבֶר". אֲבָל הַצִּבּוּר תּוֹלִין לָהֶן עָוֹן רִאשׁוֹן שֵׁנִי וּשְׁלִישִׁי שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (עמוס ב ו) "עַל שְׁלֹשָׁה פִּשְׁעֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְעַל אַרְבָּעָה לֹא אֲשִׁיבֶנּוּ". וּכְשֶׁמְּחַשְּׁבִין לָהֶן עַל דֶּרֶךְ זֶה מְחַשְּׁבִין לָהֶן מֵרְבִיעִי וְאֵילָךְ. הַבֵּינוֹנִים אִם הָיָה בִּכְלַל מֶחֱצָה עֲוֹנוֹת שֶׁלָּהֶן שֶׁלֹּא הֵנִיחַ תְּפִלִּין מֵעוֹלָם דָּנִין אוֹתוֹ כְּפִי חֶטְאוֹ וְיֵשׁ לוֹ חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. וְכֵן כָּל הָרְשָׁעִים שֶׁעֲוֹנוֹתֵיהֶן מְרֻבִּים דָּנִין אוֹתָן כְּפִי חֲטָאֵיהֶם וְיֵשׁ לָהֶן חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא שֶׁכָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל יֵשׁ לָהֶם חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁחָטְאוּ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה ס כא) "וְעַמֵּךְ כֻּלָּם צַדִּיקִים לְעוֹלָם יִירְשׁוּ אָרֶץ". אֶרֶץ זוֹ מָשָׁל כְּלוֹמַר אֶרֶץ הַחַיִּים וְהוּא הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. וְכֵן חֲסִידֵי אֻמּוֹת הָעוֹלָם יֵשׁ לָהֶם חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא:
When evaluating a person's actions, sins that occur only once or twice are not considered significant. A sin is counted only if it happens three times or more. If these repeated sins outweigh a person's good deeds, then any lesser sins are also included in the judgment. If a person's good deeds are equal to or greater than the sins committed more than three times, they receive forgiveness for their sins one by one. The third sin is forgiven as it is treated like a first sin because the earlier two were already pardoned. This pattern continues: after forgiving the third sin, the fourth is seen as a first sin and is also forgiven, following the same principle. This approach applies to an individual, as referenced in Job 33:29, which states that God will act multiple times with a person. In contrast, for a community, punishment for the first three sins is put on hold, as indicated by Amos 2:6, which says retribution is withheld for the first three sins but not for the fourth. When assessing a community's sins, the evaluation begins with the fourth sin. A Beinoni, someone whose good deeds and sins are balanced, is treated according to this method. However, if this person has never performed the mitzvah of tefillin, they will be judged based on their sins but will still receive a place in the world to come. Likewise, even those who are deemed wicked and have more sins than merits are judged on their wrongdoings but will also be granted a portion in the world to come, as every Israelite has a share, shown in Isaiah 60:21, which notes that all of God’s people are righteous and will inherit everlasting life. The same applies to the righteous among the nations, who also have a place in the world to come.

Thank you, I appreciate it
